# Error al intentar instalar npm en un proyecto

Tags: nodejs

alguna sugerencia

```
      npm ERR! code 1
     npm ERR! path 
     C:\Users\mario\OneDrive\Documentos\Konecta\CajaMedica\CajaMedica\node_modules\semantic-ui
     npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c gulp install
    npm ERR! fs.js:45
   npm ERR! } = primordials;
   npm ERR!     ^
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
   npm ERR!     at fs.js:45:5
   npm ERR!     at req_ 
   
  (C:\Users\mario\OneDrive\Documentos\Konecta\CajaMedica\CajaMedica\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
  npm ERR!     at Object.req [as require] 
   (C:\Users\mario\OneDrive\Documentos\Konecta\CajaMedica\CajaMedica\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> 
    (C:\Users\mario\OneDrive\Documentos\Konecta\CajaMedica\CajaMedica\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    npm ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
     npm ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    npm ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    npm ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\mario\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-05T12_53_27_823Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tal como está redactada tu pregunta necesita más detalles y aclaraciones para poder comprender el problema y buscar una poaible solución. Saludos

Comment: que comando deseas ejecutar o instalar? solo muestras el código del error

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que se haya instalado correctamente NPM con Node.js, para eso usa

```
node -v
```

Si no lo tienes instalado, o lo quieres reinstalar
usa:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Comment: muchas gracias ya esta solucionado!